# Passing arguments to perl using bash variables

Tags: bash, perl

Ordinarily I would invoke Perl and supply required arguments from within a bash script simply using:

```
perl script.pl arg1
```

However there are cases when I want to store both the perl script directory and the arguments in bash variables:

```
PERLDIR = "/example/directory/script.pl"
ARG1 = "40"
```

When trying to call the perl script using:

```
perl "$PERLDIR"
```

It works, however when trying to provide the argument i'm not sure of the syntax to utilise. If I use:

`perl "$PERLDIR $ARG1"` it'll attempt to open the directory:

```
/example/directory/script.pl 40
```

And throw an error.

Is there a way to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
 perl "$PERLDIR" "$ARG1"
```

When you use many variables in one string enclosed with `"` it becomes one argument.

Comment: @Borodin Will do - and will also remove my comment.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann: I realise that you're getting to know the ropes. Thank you for understanding